# Show facebook like & twitter follow buttons on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I'm trying to replicate the social media icons for my site similar to Hypebeast (http://hypebeast.com) whereby the Facebook like button and twitter follow buttons only show when you hover over the respective icons (see the example in the top right of the page).

As a starting point current code for my social icons is as follows:

```
<ul class="social-icons standard ">
<li class="twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/manofmanytastes" target="_blank"><i class="fa-twitter"></i><i class="fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<li class="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/manofmanytastes" target="_blank"><i class="fa-facebook"></i><i class="fa-facebook"></i></a><iframe class="facebook-like" src="//wwww.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmanofmanytastes&amp;width=150&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=21&amp;appId=604369196250500" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:21px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></li>
<li class="instagram"><a href="http://instagram.com/http://instagram.com/manofmanytastes" target="_blank"><i class="fa-instagram"></i><i class="fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
<li class="rss"><a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/ManOfMany" target="_blank"><i class="fa-rss"></i><i class="fa-rss"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS for the facebook iframe is:

```
#header li.facebook iframe.facebook-like {
position: absolute;
top: -30px;
left: -27px;
display: none;
}

#header li.facebook iframe.facebook-like:hover {
display: block;
}
```

I am not very experienced with coding (self-taught and a lot of mine is trial and error) Is there anyway someone can explain or provide code for this to work in http://jsfiddle.net/

I can force the like button to show if I force element state of the iframe to :hover but not if I hover the mouse over the icon or list item area at all?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:** Everything seems to be positioned correctly but I'm having trouble loading the javascript to toggle the display state on hover.

I have saved the following in social-popup.js in my child theme directory folder

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
// Your jQuery code goes here. Use $ as normal.
   $(".facebook").hover(function(){$('.facebook-like').toggle();});
$(".twitter").hover(function(){$('.twitter-follow').toggle();});
});
```

Then I have added this to the functions.php file in the child directory:

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
wp_register_script('my_amazing_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/social-popup.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_script');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

Everything else seems to be working fine & positioned correctly apart from the Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the facebook like iframe initially:

```
.facebook-like{
    display:none;
}
```

Then use jQuery's .hover function combined with .toggle to toggle the iframe on hover:

```
$(".facebook").hover(function(){$('.facebook-like').toggle()})
```

> EDIT: Updated the JSFiddle

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/s9ts65f6/3/

Comment: Thanks Jim! How would you go about doing this for the twitter Follow button as well? Would the code be the same?

Comment: Do I add the jQuery to the functions table in wordpress?

Comment: Please check out the updated JSFiddle to see how twitter would work.  It looks like you had some issues with your html also.  If you're trying to use font-awesome, the correct class name is "fa fa-facebook".  You just had "fa-facebook".  Also you had two "i" tags..not sure why.

As far as including jQuery in wordpress, I am not sure how to do that, you can check this link out:
http://matthewruddy.com/using-jquery-with-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks again Jim. All the elements seem to be there but I'm having great difficulty including the correct javascript to toggle the hover/ display state. I've edited the code above to show you what I mean.

Comment: Try changing $(document).ready(function($) to jQuery(document).ready(function($)

Comment: Hi Jim, Unfortunately that didn't seem to work either? Any ideas?

Comment: Honestly I don't know..it seems like an issue getting the jQuery to work in wordpress but I've never used wordpress so I wouldn't be much help there.